# Negative coloured icons in MFC Application

Tags: c++, mfc, icons

I've been searching the internet for days trying to find a fix to a problem my coworker is having. I'm not sure how to describe it, but the best way I think is that the program is picking random icons that should be elsewhere in the application and displaying them, like a photographic negative in the wrong location. This is only happening on her PC.

Here is an example of what it should look like: 
[image: Expected]

And here's what it actually looks like:
[image: Actual]

If anyone could point me in the right direction that'd be much appreciated.

Comment: Non unique resource IDs?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ All of the IDs are unique

Comment: You are getting inconsistent behavior, maybe some variable is not initialized or something along that line. Also try restarting Windows 10 (not shutdown)

Comment: I would bet you have a problem with an image list.

Comment: It can also be related to DPI settings. Change your computer's DPI to 125%, login/out to see if you reproduce the error.

Comment: In the registry, try to delete the application's `Workspace` subfolder. Explanation: The Application caches there its own Layout, and other customization like user-attributed keys, toolbar and menu info, etc.